# void affecting output of the program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am calling one function in which values are printed, but when `void` is added before the call, the function is not giving correct (or any) output.

I tried various methods

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void func1(); 
void func2(); 

void func1() 
{ 
    printf("Inside func1()\n"); 
} 

void func2() 
{ 
    printf("Inside func2()\n"); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    void func1(); 
    void func2(); 
    printf("Inside main()\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Output is :-

```
Inside main
```

When `void` is removed before calling `func1` and `func2`, the output is changed.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void func1(); 
void func2(); 

void func1() 
{ 
    printf("Inside func1()\n"); 
} 

void func2() 
{ 
    printf("Inside func2()\n"); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    func1(); 
    func2(); 
    printf("Inside main()\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Output is :-

```
Inside func1
Inside func2
Inside main
```

Can anyone explain how `void` is affecting desired output?

Comment: Note that none of the function declarations or definitions shown in the question involves a prototype. You would need notations such as `int main(void)` to define a prototype for `main()`.

Answer (score 5):

The statement `void func1();` within `main` is a *function declaration*. This is a no-op at runtime.

`func1();` actually calls the function.

It's how the language grammar works, that's all. It's rather clever if you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `void func1();` is not a call to the function, it just means: somewhere there may be a function with this signature, I want to use it even if it is not declared forward. Usually we call this a [function declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) and we don't use it inside `main` but at the beginning of the file.

Comment: " it just means: somewhere there is a function with this signature" There might not be. But there must be if the function is called.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the edit, but are you sure that "function declaration" is a better name than "function prototype" in this case? Maybe a matter of scope? Global=Prototype and Local=Declaration?

Comment: Prototype refers to when the types of the arguments are specified in the argument list to the function, or the keyword `void` explicitly appears to deny that there are arguments. Thus, `int main();` is a function declaration with no prototype, but `int main(void);` is a function declaration with a prototype.  As I commented below the question, there isn’t a single prototype in the code in the question. There are function declarations and definitions, but no prototypes at all.

Comment: Now, your link is to Wikipedia's article on function prototypes, so that gave me cause for thought. If you'd said something like "As Wikipedia's article on [function prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) explains, these are _function declarations_ (and function definitions); but without the type information in the parenthetical argument list, they are not function prototypes." or something similar, then you'd be fine. The article actually tries to make the case that `int main(void) { … }` is not a prototype. That's not strictly accurate; it does provide a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

A function declaration is the action to tells the compiler about a function's name, return type, and parameters.
eg:-`void func1();`

A function definition provides the actual body of the function.
eg:-

```
void func1() 
{ 
    printf("Inside func1()\n"); 
}
```

To call a function, you simply need to pass the required parameters along with the function name, and if the function returns a value, then you can store the returned value.

eg:-`func1();`

Comment: Note that `void func1();` is indeed a function declaration, but it says almost nothing about the types of the arguments.  The only thing that can be inferred is that the function is not variadic — it does not have an argument list that ends with ellipsis: `void func1(…, ...)` where there must be one named argument with type information in place of the `…` ellipsis, but the `...` triple-dot ellipsis indicates more arguments of unspecified type.   To give type information, it must be declared (in this context) as `void func(void);` — now there is type information that there are no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration **always** begins with a type name.  When you write

```
int func();
```

you are declaring to the compiler that you have a function that takes an unspecified number of parameters and returns `int` (so the compiler knows about it).

When you write

```
func();
```

you are telling the compiler to execute function `func();` and discard its result, in a normal execution statement.

Always you have a C statement ***beginning with a type identifier***
, that's not to be executed, but to inform the compiler of the existence of such thing (to declare it)

In your example, you changed two declarations at the beginning of `main()` into to execution statements.  As such, the compiler generated code to execute those, resulting in the output you got on execution.